# SetContent (TabContentFactory) для существующей вкладки

Tags: android, java

имеется `TabActivity`, в ней несколько вкладок. на одной из вкладок есть пара кнопок. при нажатии на одну из этих кнопок необходимо перестроить вкладку - убрать эти кнопки,  и вывести на передний план `ListView`.
Пытаюсь сделать это так: имплементировал `TabContentFactory`, и в методе `createTabContent` устраиваю необходимые проверки.
В момент когда нужно, я вызываю `tabSpec.setContent(this)`. но ничего не происходит. новый вид не назначается. ко всему прочему когда после нажатия кнопки задающей новый вид, я пытаюсь переключится на другую вкладку, вылазит `nullPointerException`.
помогите, как задать новый `View` для существующего экземпляра `TabSpec`?

Comment: @argamidon сделать `RelativeLayout` на него положить ListView и кнопки - переключаться между ними через `setVisibility`. м?

Comment: да я думаю это выход. спасибо.